# get value from database to set check box

Tags: android, database, checkbox, cursor

I want to build checkbox which get cursor from getLang() if KEY_ACT of language = 1 then checkbox is true

This is my getLang()

```
public Cursor getLang() {
    return db.query(LANGS_TABLE, new String[] { 
            KEY_LANG_ID,
            KEY_LANG,
            KEY_ACT},
            null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

and I have database like this

```
         ContentValues initialValues3 = new ContentValues();
        initialValues3.put(KEY_LANG, "English");
        initialValues3.put(KEY_ACT, "1");
        db.insert(LANGS_TABLE, null, initialValues3);
        initialValues3.clear();
        initialValues3.put(KEY_LANG, "French");
        initialValues3.put(KEY_ACT, "0");
        db.insert(LANGS_TABLE, null, initialValues3);
        initialValues3.clear();
        initialValues3.put(KEY_LANG, "German");
        initialValues3.put(KEY_ACT, "0");
        db.insert(LANGS_TABLE, null, initialValues3);
        initialValues3.clear();
        initialValues3.put(KEY_LANG, "Italy");
        initialValues3.put(KEY_ACT, "0");
        db.insert(LANGS_TABLE, null, initialValues3);
        initialValues3.clear();
        initialValues3.put(KEY_LANG, "Spanish");
        initialValues3.put(KEY_ACT, "0");
        db.insert(LANGS_TABLE, null, initialValues3);
        initialValues3.clear();
```

so when checkbox is show, the English must be show the select because KEY_ACT=1

and this is my checkbox code

```
protected void printSelectedLanguage(){
    int i = 0;
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getLang();
    for(i = 0; i < _options.length-1; i++ )
    {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_ACT)).equals(1)){
            _selections[i]=true;
        }
        if ( _selections[i]==true ) {
            db.setLang_Act(i+1, 1);
        }else if ( _selections[i]==false ){
            db.setLang_Act(i+1, 0);
        }
    }
```

but It's doesn't show the KEY_ACT from database

What should I do?

/// edit for show more about my check box on Alert dialog

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog( int id ) 
{
    return 
    new AlertDialog.Builder( this )
        .setTitle( "Select language" )
        .setMultiChoiceItems( _options, _selections, new DialogSelectionClickHandler() )
        .setPositiveButton( "OK", new DialogButtonClickHandler() )
        .create();}
  public class DialogSelectionClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int clicked, boolean selected )
    {
        Log.i( "MEooooo", _options[ clicked ] + " selected: " + selected );

    }
}

public class DialogButtonClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int clicked )

    {
        switch( clicked )
        {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:


                printSelectedLanguage();
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:

                printSelectedLanguage();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `"1"` instead of `1` in the `.equals()` comparison?

If `1` is true and `0` is false, you could also retrieve the field as an int:

```
if (c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_ACT)) == 1) {
```

**Edit** - you might want to pass the actual cursor, since your database setup matches the setup [setMultipleChoiceItems()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMultiChoiceItems%28android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener%29) is expecting:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder( this )
    .setTitle( "Select language" )
    .setMultiChoiceItems(cursor, KEY_ACT, KEY_LANG, new DialogSelectionClickHandler())
    .setPositiveButton( "OK", new DialogButtonClickHandler() )
    .create();
```

Comment: can you paste the code where you actually enable/set the checkbox?

Comment: please see my edit from this code it can choose language already but it doesn't show the check (KEY_ACT=1) from database

Comment: and how about printSelectedLanguage() what should I do?

Comment: Wow it show now ^^ but printSelectedLanguage() doesn't work what should I do next please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198868/how-to-code-to-set-check-box-value-into-database  please help

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off storing KEY_ACT as a boolean or int wouldn't you? That way it works more fluidly with a checkbox.

Have you made sure to call c.moveToNext() or c.moveToFirst() to get the records in the cursor?

Don't forget to call c.close() after you have finished with the cursor as well, to keep your application tidy.